# React/React-Router: Using A Controller-View that Contains Routes For onEnter Transitions

Tags: routes, reactjs, react-router, flux

**What I'm trying to do:**

**I wanted to use onEnter hooks the same way that [auth flow example uses them to do page transitions](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js#L122)** depending on whether the user is logged in our not.

But in my case I want to use the state of the program to manage transitions meaning that **my route handlers need access to the state of the controller-view.**

**What I did:**

So **I made a root.js component** [like @dan_abramov did in his flux react-router example](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example/blob/master/scripts/Root.js#L16) that contains the route handlers **but I then extended it to be the main controller-view.**

### This way the state can be checked during onEnter hooks to manage special transitions depending on the program state.

---

**Code:**

Here is a bare-bones example of the Root Component that has access to state  so it can used by the onEnter Hooks.

**(Note: Haven't seen react-router used this way exactly so I'm suspicious of it as a design choice)**

**Root.js**(a controller-view that contains routes)

```
import UserStore from '../stores/UserStore';

function getStateFromStores() {
  return {
   user: UserStore.get() 
  };


var Root = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        user: null
    };
},


componentDidMount: function() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
   UserStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
},


_enterMain: function(nextState, replaceState) {
      if(this.state.user.active === false){
        //Do some transition logic
      }
      else{
       //Do different transition logic
      }
},
//NOTE: "this.props.user" WILL BE UNDEFINED IN "Main" COMPONENT
<Router >
    <Route path='/' component={Main} onEnter={this._enterMain} user={this.state.user}>
     ...
    </Route>
</Router>

  _onChange: function() {

    this.setState(getStateFromStores());
  }

});

export default Root;
```

**Problem With Code:**

**Any state I try to pass down to the Route handlers as a prop becomes undefined** in the component it was passed into.

It seems like a logical thing to do, but so far - **it doesn't seem like React-Router intends to be used this way.(Which makes me even more suspicious of my design choice using Root.js as a controller-view containing state and routes).**

---

**Questions:**

1)Is it acceptable practice to combine the root controller-view with the route handlers?(like Root.js component above)

2) Should onEnter Hooks be accessing program state to manage page transitions?

3) Is passing state down state into the route handlers valid? If so, how can I stop the props from being undefined.